# Добавление дополнений в игру

Tags: java, javafx, разработка-игр

Моя программа - это справочное приложение по настольной игре. В ней довольно много параметров (число монстров на карте, отслеживание игровых событий, здоровье игроков и др.), следить за которыми игрокам трудно в течение долгого времени.

Однако возникла следующая проблема - у данной настольной игры есть дополнения, расширяющие список возможных событий. Покажу на конкретном примере (постараюсь не слишком сильно углубляться в детали игры):

Каждый раунд в одной из игровых зон (одной из 12) должны появиться Врата в Иной мир. Если в этой зоне уже есть Врата, происходит событие "Наплыв монстров". Для этих двух событий были сделаны кнопки, при нажатии которых выводятся подсказки (что происходит в этом случае), а приложение будет показывать, что открыто столько-то врат, на карте столько-то монстров (если Врат слишком много, игра проиграна). Игроки могут запечатать врата, положив туда особую метку. В локациях с меткой Врата не появляются.

В дополнении к этой игре появилось событие "Прорыв Врат" - если в локации есть метка, она снимается, и Врата появляются как обычно.

А теперь вопрос: какие есть инструменты в Java, позволяющие выборочно добавлять элементы и механики в игру? Причем не постоянными if-проверками при каждом чихе, а так, чтобы в начале игры пользователь выбирает используемые дополнения (из-за сложности игры обычно используют одно дополнение из возможных) в начале игры, после чего эти элементы (кнопки, прослушиватели событий и т. д.) добавляются в текущую игру.

В качестве графической платформы используется JavaFX, приложение для компьютера.

P.S. Настольная игра называется "Ужас Аркхэма" (вдруг, кто-то знает).

P.P.S. Я новичок в Java, так что многих особенностей языка пока ещё не знаю.